# BASH WHILE loop not hitting CASE switch

Tags: bash, while-loop, switch-statement

Hey guys title pretty much says it, but I'm echoing two variables into a BASH loop to kick it off, and (supposedly) using a `case` to be able to identify where they are and run a similar but separate (missing -k flag on second go around) `wget` statement. I hit my `git checkout` but it doesn't seem like I'm entering my cases. How do I fix this, or is there a better way to do it since I'm just dropping a -k flag?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "render\nstorage" | while read x; do 

    git checkout "$x"

    case $x in
        $1)
          wget "${WGDOMAIN}" -r -l INF -k -p        \
            --no-check-certificate                  \
            --strict-comments                       \
            --warc-header="Operator: Web Archiver"  \
            --warc-file="$WGDOMAIN"                 \
            --warc-dedup="${WGDOMAIN}.cdx"          \
            --warc-cdx=on 2> session.log
        ;;

        $2)
          wget "${WGDOMAIN}" -r -l INF -p           \
            --no-check-certificate                  \
            --strict-comments                       \
            --warc-header="Operator: Web Archiver"  \
            --warc-file="$WGDOMAIN"                 \
            --warc-dedup="${WGDOMAIN}.cdx"          \
            --warc-cdx=on 2> session.log
        ;;

        $1|$2)
          git add . && git ci -m"Archived: ${DATE}"
          git push origin "$x"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: the arguments need to be the options actually coming in, IE `render` and `storage` or `render | storage`. Just figured out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Can you add more details on how you use your script?

Comment: it's not clear how you want to use this. if you call this script as `./myscript.sh storage render` it will first run the `$1` case, and then the `$2` case; if you run it `./myscript.sh render storage` it will run them in reverse order; the `$1|$2` case will never be true, as the cases have already been handled.

Comment: @ehime if you figured out what was wrong, please add the solution as an *answer* and *accept* it, so people don't get confused.

Comment: ^ i agree, what I was trying to do was use the echo'd in parameters instead of command line parameters to evaluate the expression, I just had it backwards for some reason =/ late night at the office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Called with no positional parameters your script will not do anything inside the case statement as $1 and $2 are empty. Besides that, the last case option $1|$2 will never be reached as the prior ones will match. May be you should get that commands out of the case.